# Поиск по строкам с regex на Java

Tags: java

1.Как сделать чтобы при указанном regexp выражении, шёл поиск строк в файле по этому выражению, игнорируя регистр слов? `CASE_INSENSITIVE` работает только для латинских букв.

2.Работая с regexp, для считывания строк из файла лучше использовать Scanner или BufferedReader?

К примеру regex выражение `[\"+у+\"]`

Нужно чтобы были найдены две строки из файла:

> получили по заслугам.
> полУчили по заслУгам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для требуемого поиска, нечувствительного к регистру, по кириллице или символам других алфавитов, кроме английского, нужно дополнительно использовать флажок [`Pattern.UNICODE_CASE` (?u)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CASE):

```java
String str = """
привет        
получили по заслугам.
полУчили по заслУгам.
пока
""";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[У]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);

System.out.println("String::matches:\n\t" + 
    str.lines()
       .filter(s -> s.matches("(?iu).*[У].*"))
       .collect(Collectors.joining("\n\t"))
);
System.out.println("Pattern::find:\n\t" + 
    str.lines()
       .filter(s -> p.matcher(s).find())
       .collect(Collectors.joining("\n\t"))
);
```

Вывод:

```
String::matches:
    получили по заслугам.
    полУчили по заслУгам.
Pattern::find:
    получили по заслугам.
    полУчили по заслУгам.
```